# RestKit.h Not Found When Building With Xcode Product > Profile

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, restkit

I have an app that uses RestKit 0.10.2 and I can build and run the app just fine in the Xcode 4.4.1 simulator using iOS 5.1.1. I can also run Analyze without any issues. However, when I go to try and Profile the app, the build fails with Lexical or Preprocessor Issue RestKit/Reskit.h file not found.

Here's what I have in Header Search Paths > Debug on the target:

```
$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../three20
$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../three20
"$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../Headers"
```

What could I be missing? When I upgraded from 0.94 to 0.10.2 I completely removed Restkit from my project and re-imported it because I was having a lot of issues trying to get this exact same problem resolved for a normal run. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Profile uses a Release build by default, not Debug (since it makes no sense to profile a debug build).  Make sure Header Search Path -> Release is also filled in.

Comment: I swear I had looked at release at least 20 times. I had entered a variation of "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../Headers" but the path wasn't quite right. Thanks for the answer.